# Why :hover changes just background-color, but doesn't change link color?

Tags: css

I do the navigation for a website and when I try to make :hover, it changes just background-color, but doesn't change the colour of links, why?

I tried lot of things, but it doesn't work as well. Probably I make some mistakes.

HTML:

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Как добраться</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    color:blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 7px 5px 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #3a3939;
    border-color: black;
}

li:hover{  /* Here looks everything fine */
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: black;
    color: black;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the color on li:hover to change text color but also set color to inherit on the a:link itself

```css
ul {
    color:blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 7px 5px 8px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #3a3939;
    border-color: black;
}

li:hover{  /* Here looks everything fine */
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: black;
    color: black; /* Add this here */
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: inherit; /* make this color reflect li:hover's color using inherit*/
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Новости</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Как добраться</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things: first, your `hover` block only changes the `background-color` rather than the `color`. Second, you are changing the properties of the `li` element rather than the `a` child element.

To change the properties of the link inside the `li`, consider this:

```
li:hover a {
    color: red;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: now link background changes, but button color still same

Comment: I adjusted my answer to only change the link in the `li` block. Hopefully it at least guides you in the right direction as to which blocks of CSS needs to be changed to affect different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:
`li:hover > a:link { color: black; }`

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
li:hover > a{
    color:#000;
}
```